# Pass column from db query result to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, array-column

I'm trying to write a SQL query to hit my WordPress database as I need some of the info for my front end. However, I'm not getting anything from it. I can see the info in the database itself, so something is wrong with my query string.

```
$priceQuery = "SELECT `option_value` FROM {$wpdb->prefix}`options` WHERE `option_name` = 'apv_price'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($priceQuery, 'ARRAY_A');
```

I'm using the following `<script>` to log out my info to the browser:

```
<script>
  console.log("results: ", <?php echo implode(",", $results) ?>);
</script>
```

However, all I get is `result:` in my console. I used the CodeWP AI to help me write this, and it suggested the `{$wpdb->prefix}` for the query. The table is fully titled `wp_options`. I've tried the query with both and still get no result. Does anybody see where I went wrong?
Thanks.

Edited to add image of info in DB:
[image]

Comment: What does `var_dump($results);` show?

Comment: @Barmar I get this: `var_dump: array(0) {
}`

Comment: That means there were no options with that option name.

Comment: Instead, you can use directly get_option() like: `<?php echo get_option('apv_price'); ?>`

Comment: I added a screenshot of the info in the database. In this particular instance, this price is not related to the `$product`.

Comment: For WordPress data stored in `wp_options` table, better use WordPress built in [`get_option()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) instead of a custom sql query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$results` is a 2-dimensional array -- each element of the array is a row of the results represented as an associative array.

So use `array_column($results, 'option_value')` to get the array of values, and implode this.

You also need to quote the resulting string when substituting it into JavaScript. Use `json_encode()` to convert it to a properly formated JavaScript string.

```
  console.log("results: ", <?php echo json_encode(implode(",", array_column($results, 'option_value'))); ?>);
```